# can't open source file "sys/reent.h" (dependency of freertos/FreeRTOS.h)

Tags: iot, esp32, esp-idf

I'm using visual studio code version(1.59.1) for ESP-IDF version (4.3).I have added in `c_cpp_properties.json` file all paths in  `includepath` but I still have the same all error gone except this one:

> (can't open source file "sys/reent.h" (dependency of freertos/FreeRTOS.h)).

In visual studio terminal it gives me error when I try to use (`idf.py` command)

> 'idf.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, and sometimes it give me python can't open the file where the script exist.

Answer (score 1):

First open esp-idf terminal then execute "idf.py build" or other idf commands.
Once build success "sys/reent.h" error will gone

Comment: thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I follow this [solution](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=16585#p69944) by modifying c_cpp_properties.json.
My version:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",

        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components/**",
            "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components/**"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components",
                "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
        },
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.20348.0",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "compilerPath": "${config:idf.toolsPath}/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc",
        "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}